# How to use SQL Server to iterate through similar rows with exists operator and output rows that meet certain running total conditions

Tags: sql-server

I need to be able to treat each row as if it was an 'incoming' row into the table and compare it to previous transactions, and when certain conditions are met, output only that row.

For example, I want to output the most recent row if it has 3 or more occurrences on the same accounts, that the current row is occurring within 30 minutes of the previous row, and all rows previous rows and the current row has a total amount of 400 or more.

```
CREATE TABLE #table 
(
    tran_date DATETIME, 
    acct INT, 
    amt INT
)

INSERT INTO #table 
VALUES ('2019-07-01 01:21:08', 1, 100), ('2019-07-01 01:30:50', 1, 200),
       ('2019-07-01 01:46:21', 1, 150), ('2019-07-01 03:23:41', 1, 50),
       ('2019-07-01 03:24:40', 1, 300), ('2019-07-01 09:53:28', 2, 400),
       ('2019-07-01 12:56:15', 2, 50), ('2019-07-01 17:43:55', 2, 500),
       ('2019-07-01 05:15:54', 3, 20), ('2019-07-01 05:30:00', 3, 50),
       ('2019-07-01 05:36:27', 3, 10), ('2019-07-01 05:59:00', 3, 250),
       ('2019-07-01 06:18:00', 3, 80), ('2019-07-01 06:25:56', 3, 100),
       ('2019-07-01 09:34:34', 4, 150), ('2019-07-01 09:47:24', 4, 300),
       ('2019-07-01 09:52:25', 4, 50), ('2019-07-01 11:34:34', 4, 250),
       ('2019-07-01 11:47:24', 4, 100), ('2019-07-01 11:52:25', 4, 150)
```

My goal is to try and get a way that can do this in SQL using the exists operator, if it can also be done without creating several temp table and joining them back together I would be thankful for that. I'm trying to avoid having to do several joins for certain reasons.

```
select *
from #table a
where exists (select 1 
              from #table b
              where a.acct = b.acct
                and b.tran_date >= dateadd(minute, -30, a.tran_date) 
                and b.tran_date < a.tran_date
              having sum(amt) >= 400 and count(*) >= 3)
```

I expect the query to output these rows if i did my math right:

```
tran_date           acct amt  
------------------------------
2019-07-01 01:46:21  1   150 
2019-07-01 06:18:00  3    80  
2019-07-01 06:25:56  3   100
2019-07-01 09:52:25  4    50
2019-07-01 11:52:25  4   150
```

So the first row here is picked up because it is the 3rd transaction, all previous are within 30 minutes of the row before it, and this is the transaction that reaches $400 or more of the total amount for the 3 previous.

My current query returns no output, and I think it is something to do with the having clause. I could be wrong but help with this would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
In the end I would need the row numbers or rankings for each row to look like this:

```
tran_date           acct    amt RN  Time_Diff   Running_Total
2019-07-01 01:21:08.000 1   100 1   NULL          100
2019-07-01 01:30:50.000 1   200 2   9             300
2019-07-01 01:46:21.000 1   150 3   16            450
2019-07-01 03:23:41.000 1   50  1   97            50
2019-07-01 03:24:40.000 1   300 2   1             350
2019-07-01 09:53:28.000 2   400 1   NULL          400
2019-07-01 12:56:15.000 2   50  1   183           50
2019-07-01 17:43:55.000 2   500 1   287           500
2019-07-01 05:15:54.000 3   20  1   NULL          20
2019-07-01 05:30:00.000 3   50  2   15            70
2019-07-01 05:36:27.000 3   10  3   6             80
2019-07-01 05:59:00.000 3   250 4   23            330
2019-07-01 06:18:00.000 3   80  5   19            410
2019-07-01 06:25:56.000 3   100 6   7             510
2019-07-01 09:34:34.000 4   150 1   NULL          150
2019-07-01 09:47:24.000 4   300 2   13            450
2019-07-01 09:52:25.000 4   50  3   5             500
2019-07-01 11:34:34.000 4   250 1   102           250
2019-07-01 11:47:24.000 4   100 2   13            350
2019-07-01 11:52:25.000 4   150 3   5             550
```

The goal is that once the rows are no longer <= 30 minutes apart from each other or the acct # changes, the row number or rank restarts, along with restarting the running total of the amount. If I have it in a format like this then I can query for the results rows I want.

Comment: Hi!  Are you aware that internally a WHERE EXISTS is implemented exactly the same way as a JOIN?  Why do you think you should avoid using JOIN to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without temp tables here's an option which would require a couple sub-queries.

- You'll need [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get the number of minutes between tran_date and the previous row.
- Then basically a running total on the evaluation of whether or not the time difference is greater than 30. So you know when to reset your numbering.
- Then you can use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [SUM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) partitioning it by the acct and your "reset" indicator.

Here's a working example:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [tran_date] DATETIME
      , [acct] INT
      , [amt] INT
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES ( '2019-07-01 01:21:08', 1, 100 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 01:30:50', 1, 200 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 01:46:21', 1, 150 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 03:23:41', 1, 50 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 03:24:40', 1, 300 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 09:53:28', 2, 400 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 12:56:15', 2, 50 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 17:43:55', 2, 500 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 05:15:54', 3, 20 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 05:30:00', 3, 50 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 05:36:27', 3, 10 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 05:59:00', 3, 250 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 06:18:00', 3, 80 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 06:25:56', 3, 100 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 09:34:34', 4, 150 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 09:47:24', 4, 300 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 09:52:25', 4, 50 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 11:34:34', 4, 250 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 11:47:24', 4, 100 )
     , ( '2019-07-01 11:52:25', 4, 150 );


--Read comments from inner most sub query out

SELECT   [b].[tran_date]
        , [b].[acct]
        , [b].[amt]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [b].[acct], [b].[diffincrement] ORDER BY [b].[tran_date]) AS [RN]  --Third:  We can now partition on our acct and "reset" indicator(diffincrement) to get our row number.
        , [b].[Time_Diff]
        , SUM([b].[amt]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [b].[acct], [b].[diffincrement] ORDER BY [b].[tran_date]) AS [Running_Total] --Third:  We can now partition on our acct and "reset" indicator(diffincrement) to get our running total.
FROM     (   --Second:  Here we now evalute Time_Diff and sum to basically give a running total so we know when to reset based on that.
             SELECT *
                  , SUM(CASE WHEN [a].[Time_Diff] >= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                       ) OVER ( PARTITION BY [a].[acct] ORDER BY [a].[tran_date]) AS [diffincrement]
                 FROM   (
                            --First:  Here we use LAG and datediff to find the different in minutes of the previous row.
                            SELECT *
                                 , DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG([tran_date], 1, [tran_date]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [acct] ORDER BY [tran_date]), [tran_date]) AS [Time_Diff]
                            FROM   @TestData
                        ) AS [a]
         ) AS [b]
ORDER BY [b].[acct]
       , [b].[tran_date];
```

Giving you the final result of:

```
tran_date               acct        amt         RN                   Time_Diff   Running_Total
----------------------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- -------------
2019-07-01 01:21:08.000 1           100         1                    0           100
2019-07-01 01:30:50.000 1           200         2                    9           300
2019-07-01 01:46:21.000 1           150         3                    16          450
2019-07-01 03:23:41.000 1           50          1                    97          50
2019-07-01 03:24:40.000 1           300         2                    1           350
2019-07-01 09:53:28.000 2           400         1                    0           400
2019-07-01 12:56:15.000 2           50          1                    183         50
2019-07-01 17:43:55.000 2           500         1                    287         500
2019-07-01 05:15:54.000 3           20          1                    0           20
2019-07-01 05:30:00.000 3           50          2                    15          70
2019-07-01 05:36:27.000 3           10          3                    6           80
2019-07-01 05:59:00.000 3           250         4                    23          330
2019-07-01 06:18:00.000 3           80          5                    19          410
2019-07-01 06:25:56.000 3           100         6                    7           510
2019-07-01 09:34:34.000 4           150         1                    0           150
2019-07-01 09:47:24.000 4           300         2                    13          450
2019-07-01 09:52:25.000 4           50          3                    5           500
2019-07-01 11:34:34.000 4           250         1                    102         250
2019-07-01 11:47:24.000 4           100         2                    13          350
2019-07-01 11:52:25.000 4           150         3                    5           500
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your example is that HAVING COUNT() does not work the way you expect.

Consider the following query

```
SELECT
  tran_date, acct, amt,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acct ORDER BY tran_date) AS RN
FROM #table
```

This will give you the number of each row per account

Then

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    tran_date, acct, amt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acct ORDER BY tran_date) AS RN
  FROM #table
) X
WHERE RN >= 3
```

will give you all the row with 3 or more.

Oh, you want the last one?  You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    tran_date, acct, amt,c
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acct ORDER BY tran_date ASC) AS RN,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acct ORDER BY tran_date DESC) AS RN_REV
  FROM #table
) X
WHERE RN >= 3 AND RN_REV = 1
```

Comment: Hey Hogan, thanks for the help, but it's not exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. I also need to restart the row count whenever the time difference between two rows with the same acct is greater than 30 minutes. I'm not necessarily looking for the last row for each acct, I only want the row that meets the conditions I specified earlier.

Comment: @Steveiepete -- just add that criteria to the partition.  The point of my answer was not exactly what you were trying to do (since it was not clear) but an approach to this type of problem in SQL

Comment: @Steveiepete -- For example it is not clear to me what happens when there is more than than one item that happens within 30 minutes of another -- do all the items get counted?  Is it just the first two and the 3rd item stands alone (or gets paired with the 4th?)  Maybe it is neither of these and you want to divide a day  up in 48 half hour "chunks".  The requirements you give are not clear on any of this.

Comment: @Hogan-- I just edited my question to better reflect what I need. I have it currently to where I get the Time difference between the rows correctly, but I cant figure out how to get the row numbers to restart whenever the time difference is > 30, and then for the running total to restart with it.

Comment: @Steveiepete -- still don't understand - -are you saying the difference between any two rows can't be greater than 30 mins?

Comment: Yes, and if the difference is greater the 30 minutes then the row number would need to restart back to 1.

Comment: You can use LAG() to look at the prior number